# Find out the missing properties resources

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am very new to this semantic web and I am doing some experiments with Sparql & DBPEDIA. I wrote a query to find out all the records which has firstName(givenName) and lastName(surName).

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select count(DISTINCT ?x) where {
?x foaf:givenName ?y;
foaf:surname ?z.
}
```

When I run this query I got 9,80,000 records. But when I ran the individual queries (for firstName and lastName) I got 9,92,000 records for firstName and 9,80,000 for lastName.

Here my question is how can I get the resources which has only firstName but not the lastName...???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-pattern) clause with a `FILTER` to achieve this:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?x) AS ?count)
WHERE
{
  ?x foaf:givenName ?y .
  FILTER(NOT EXISTS { ?x foaf:surname ?z. })
}
```

This filters out matches for `?x` where the `NOT EXISTS` pattern is also matched.

Alternatively you can use the [`MINUS`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-minus) clause which does roughly the same bar some [minor differences](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-notexists-minus) which won't affect your query:

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?x) AS ?count)
WHERE
{
  ?x foaf:givenName ?y .
  MINUS { ?x foaf:surname ?z. }
}
```